# SQLite in Android to copy from one table to another works for one table and doesnt for the next table with identifcal synatx

Tags: android, database, sqlite, sql-update, sqliteopenhelper

i have two tables, an FP_master table and a Take_Away_pack_details table. my first code below successfully copies data to column TakeAwayPkCost in table FP_master from column Pack_Cost in table Take_Away_Pack_Details.

In the second case I have a third table called View_Cart_Temp and I try to copy data from Column TakeAwayPKType in the FP_Master table to column Pack_type in the 3rd table View_Cart_temp. The 2nd piece of SQlite UPDATE code is shown below. The Syntax are identical in both cases and when i run this in my app, there is no error but the column is not updated. When I run this also in the DB Browser for SQLite, I get a message saying successfully updated but when i check the table its still null and no data has been copied. What could I be missing?

```
UPDATE FP_Master SET TakeAwayPkCost = (SELECT Pack_Cost FROM Take_Away_Pack_Details WHERE Pack_Type = TakeAwayPkType)


UPDATE View_Cart_Temp SET Pack_Type = (SELECT TakeAwayPkType FROM FP_Master WHERE Item = SKU)
```

Comment: Without actual example data and the table definitions it's impossible to say. However I suspect that   `SELECT TakeAwayPkType FROM FP_Master WHERE Item = SKU` is selecting nothing and thus that it is updating the Pack_Type column with null. i.e. what is missing could well be any Item's that match SKU.

Comment: All the columns in FP_Master are populated with Data for the 2nd query from the first query and all but the Pack_Type column in the View_Cart_Temp table are populated. The expectation then is that the code will populate the one empty column from the FP_Master table. I just checked again to double confirm after you called this possible sceanrio